# Where can I query an oracle databases' case-sensitivity?

Tags: oracle, collation, case-sensitive

Where can I query the current case-sensitivity setting of an oracle database?

I've tried looking in `v$database`, `nls_database_parameters`, and looking through the system packages, but none of them seem to provide the information I need...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Oracle 10gR2`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
WHERE   parameter IN ('NLS_COMP', 'NLS_SORT')

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = 'LINGUISTIC'
  2  /

Session altered
SQL> SELECT  COUNT(*)
  2  FROM    dual
  3  WHERE   'a' = 'A'
  4  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1

SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_COMP = 'BINARY'
  2  /

Session altered
SQL> SELECT  COUNT(*)
  2  FROM    dual
  3  WHERE   'a' = 'A'
  4  /

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

From [**documentation**](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams120.htm):

> `NLS_COMP` specifies the collation behavior of the database session.
>
> Values:
>
> - `BINARY`
>
>   Normally, comparisons in the `WHERE` clause and in `PL/SQL` blocks is binary unless you specify the `NLSSORT` function.
> - `LINGUISTIC`
>
>   Comparisons for all `SQL` operations in the `WHERE` clause and in `PL/SQL` blocks should use the linguistic sort specified in the `NLS_SORT` parameter. To improve the performance, you can also define a linguistic index on the column for which you want linguistic comparisons.
> - `ANSI`
>
>   A setting of `ANSI` is for backwards compatibility; in general, you should set `NLS_COMP` to `LINGUISTIC`

Comment: What are the possible values of NLS_COMP, and how do they correspond to case-sensitivity?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers already given be aware that case sensitivity changes in 11g - e.g. see the 11g documentation re passwords.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle 10gR2 (and later), the parameters are NLS_COMP and NLS_SORT.

```
select * from v$nls_parameters where parameter in ('NLS_COMP','NLS_SORT');
```

(These parameters are set at the session level.  The settings for a session are inherited from the database setting, unless overridden by setting an OS environment variable, or an ALTER SESSION statement.)

If you want "case-insensitive" sorting and string matching, you can try these settings:

```
alter session set NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI;
alter session set NLS_COMP=LINGUISTIC;
```

Those aren't the only settings for the parameters, of course.  Oracle 10gR2 documentation:

[10gR2 Linguistic Sorting and String Searching](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG005)